# How can I increment +1 value everytime I use a login() method ? Everytime I use this method, its showing me same result being "1"

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,age,gender,login_attempts,reset_login_attempts=0):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.login_attempts = 0
        self.reset_login_attempts = reset_login_attempts
    def describe_user(self):
        data = {}
        data["first name"] = self.first_name
        data["last name"] = self.last_name
        data["age"] = self.age
        data["gender"] = self.gender
        for keys,values in data.items():
            print(f"{keys}  :  {values}")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"\nHello {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}")

    def login(self):
        
        self.login_attempts += 1
        print(f"{self.login_attempts} times logged in")
        


user1 = User('vishesh',"Bajpayee",20,"Male",0,)
user2 = User('abcd','efgf',20,'Female',0)

user1.login()
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It's not readable right now.

Comment: Please add some more details about what you are trying to achieve, what you have been trying out and especially on what is not working as expected. Include error messages. Otherwise it will be very hard to provide helpful answers.

Comment: You get that because `login_attempts` is an object attribute i.e it's specific to an object

Comment: Your code works for me, please post what happens, when you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Make `login_attempts` a class variable so that you can track the number of attempts login is called irrespective of the credentials

```
class User:

    login_attempts = 0

    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,age,gender,login_attempts,reset_login_attempts=0):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.reset_login_attempts = reset_login_attempts

    def describe_user(self):
        data = {}
        data["first name"] = self.first_name
        data["last name"] = self.last_name
        data["age"] = self.age
        data["gender"] = self.gender
        for keys,values in data.items():
            print(f"{keys}  :  {values}")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"\nHello {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}")

    def login(self):
        User.login_attempts += 1
        print(f"{User.login_attempts} times logged in")
        


user1 = User('vishesh',"Bajpayee",20,"Male",0,)
user2 = User('abcd','efgf',20,'Female',0)

user1.login()
user2.login()
```

OR

If you want to track the number of attempts made by a particular user, your code is working fine and call the login method again using the same object to see the increment in the variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you put the login function inside the class which make it a local function that is exclusive for the object itself which is user1 and user2. You can fix the problem by putting the login_attempts outside the class which make it a global function.